# How to route to a specific custom Rails 5 API version?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-api, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm developing an application which backend is being written in rails 5 api (beta version).

My API will have some versions, and I'm using this approach to address versioning:

https://github.com/iamvery/rails-api-example/blob/master/config/routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  def api_version(version, &routes)
    api_constraint = ApiConstraint.new(version: version)
    scope(module: "v#{version}", constraints: api_constraint, &routes)
  end

  api_version(1) do
    resources :articles, only: :index
  end

  api_version(2) do
    resources :articles, only: :index
  end
end
```

The thing is when I don't specify a version, it shows me an (obviuos) error (`ActionController::RoutingError: No route matches [GET] \...`).

But I'd like to route using latest api version instead throwing an error.

Comment: How do you want the url to look when not specifying version?

Comment: I'm passing api version number through header. When I don't specify a specific version, rails should use the default one.

Answer (score 4):

**Your routes.rb file**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
scope module: :v1, constraints: ApiConstraints.new(version: 1, default: true) do
# Then for a new version create a new scope
end    
end
```

**Create a new api_constraints.rb file in the `app/lib` directory**

```
class ApiConstraints
  def initialize(options)
    @version = options[:version]
    @default = options[:default]
  end
  def matches?(req)
    @default || req.headers['Accept'].include?("application/vnd.marketplace.v#{@version}")
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I would add a root route, and use a simple redirect, like this:

```
root to: redirect('/api/v2')
```

I believe this could be done dynamically, by a little more change, something like this:

```
@versions = []

def api_version(version)
  @versions << versions
  # The rest of your code..
end

root to: redirect("/v#{@versions.max}")
```

I hope this helps.